# I create a maven project in Eclipse, on the top of my project folder appears a little letter 'M', but does not appear the little letter 'J'. Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In the universtiy we have to create a maven project in Eclipse. If I create a maven project in Eclipse, on the top of my project folder appears a little letter 'M' (Maven-project). My classmathes also created a maven project and for them automatically appeard a little letter 'J' (Java-project) as well as the little letter 'M'. Why is that and how it is posbbile to change?

Comment: Please describe the steps you took to create your project

Comment: @RobinTopper:  File -> New -> Other -> Maven -> Maven Project -> (here I have chosen Create a simple project (skip archetype selection) then I clicked Next -> then I have given the artifactID the groupID, I have chosen the version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and then packaging is jar. -> Finish.

Comment: You should add the steps you took to your question instead of posting them as a comment. Just went through the same steps and got a project with 'M' and 'J' .... Can't you compare your steps with the steps your classmates took? And check if they have installed plugins in Eclipse

Comment: My classmates did the same steps, though.